# How to unfocus current element?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I use `(document.activeElement as HTMLElement).blur();` and it works.
But when I press Tab after that, the focus moves forward one element, which is why I think about how to make the focus go to the previous element every time the command `(document.activeElement as HTMLElement).blur();` fires.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear to me. What you're describing is how tabbing through elements and focus works. What it sounds like you might be trying to do is stop focus from moving from the element you set actively with blur even when a user uses the tab key?

Comment: @Loktar , I mean, for example, I'm focused on html-element (what html-element - doesn't matter) and I try to unfocus it. I use hotkey, command `(document.activeElement as HTML-Element).blur();` fires and it get unfocused. Then I want to focus on it again. I press Tab, but I focus on the next HTML-element, which is one step ahead of the one I originally focused on. It seems that when I removed the focus from the element, then supposedly a certain focus "cursor" moved one step forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your response to my comment (Appreciate it!) the only way I know how to do something like this is to keep track globally of the last active element and then restore it.

In the example below I save the last focused element when a user hits space (the key I chose to make an element blur). When a user presses `tab` or `shift tab` if we happen to have a saved element we prevent it's default action (which would be going to the next or previous element). Instead we manually set the focused element to the one we saved. We then make sure to clear the saved state.

```js
let lastFocused = null;

document.body.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if (e.code === 'Space') {
    lastFocused = document.activeElement
    document.activeElement.blur();
  }

  if (e.code === 'Tab') {
    if (lastFocused) {
      e.preventDefault()
      lastFocused.focus();
      lastFocused = null;
    }
  }
});
```

Here is a working example as well

```js
let lastFocused = null;

document.body.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if (e.code === 'Space') {
    lastFocused = document.activeElement
    document.activeElement.blur();
  }

  if (e.code === 'Tab') {
    if (lastFocused) {
      e.preventDefault()
      lastFocused.focus();
      lastFocused = null;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<p>Press Space to unfocus an element, then press tab or shift+tab to continue on that element</p>

<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
```